# Activity Not FOund Exception While Opening File android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm getting this exception

```
06-28 21:00:48.792: W/System.err(10272): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/01 - 3G - Kaise Bataaoon [SongsPK.info] (2).mp3 typ=audio/mpeg }
```

I'm trying to open this file via these code :

```
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                            Intent intnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                            String ext = fileToOpen.substring(fileToOpen.lastIndexOf('.')+1) ;
                            //Intent j = Intent.createChooser(intnt, "Choose an application to open with:");
                            //startActivity(j);
                            File fl = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ fileToOpen);
                            if(fl.exists())
                            {
                                Log.d("FILEMANAGERACTIVITY",fl.getPath() + "0"+ ext);
                                MimeTypeMap mim = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                                String type= mim.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                                intnt.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fl) , type);
                                startActivity(intnt);
                            }
```

Comment: You might want to install a file manager app on the device, and see what happens when you click on that file.  If it works, run logcat and see what it says about the Intent used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the data and type you are sending in `intnt.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fl) , type);` is correct, seems like the Intent.ACTION_VIEW do not have any match for that intent data and hence there's no activity to handle that intent...

Regards!

Comment: thank you , it worked.
i just wanted to know that how i can open the set of programs that support that file as when i open picture it opens in defualt gallery

Comment: dont forget to mark it as correct, so for future questions people will take the time to answer :)

Comment: Ok, the intent you are using is actually for the default functionality, if you want something more specific you would have to create your own viewer...

Answer (score 1):

add the activty to mainfist.xml may help you